# display horizontal lines between menu items

Tags: css, menu

how to display horizontal lines between each menu items in this site as in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this to your css file:

```
.menu-item-depth-3 ul li a {
    border-bottom:1px solid blue;
}
```

Feel free to adjust the color of the border.

If you don't want the border on the last item you can just add a class to the `li` item called `last` and also add this to your css

```
.menu-item-depth-3 ul li.last a {
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

Comment: Wow @Marius solving CSS issues... Its encouraging..

Comment: you are helping me from so many years.

thanks a lot king of magento....